# Flutter Refresh grid view with selected item

Tags: flutter, gridview, selecteditem

I have a flutter grid view with multiple selection.

Each time I select an item, it goes inside the SelectedList and i can see a blue tick on each element.

But each time I add a new element, I  update the the list and the Consumer receive the notification, I can see the new elements but I lost all the previous selected item.

Only the GridItemCustom is impacted for the CustomExercises.

Does someone has an idea, on how to keep the previous selected elements?

it look like that once the new list is updated, i have to check if the image has been selected or not..

In the video, I select 'Superman' and then add 'Test145', then I lost the selected item 'Superman'...

[image: Multiple selection in grid view]

```
Future<void> updateOnceCustomExercisesList() async {
return this._memoizer.runOnce(() async {
  List<ExerciseItem> newList = await dbHelper!
      .findCustomExercises(widget.status == "cooldown" ? true : false);
  exerciseLoader.updateList(newList); -> does nofify ExerciseLoader Consumer
});
```

}

```
Text('Custom Exercises'),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: updateOnceCustomExercisesList(),
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  print("ERROR\n");
                }
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.done:
                    return Container();

                  default:
                    return buildLoadingScreen();
                }
              },
            ),
            Consumer<ExerciseLoader>(
              builder: (context, customExercises, child) =>
                  GridView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount:
                          customExercises.getCustomExercises().length,
                      gridDelegate:
                          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisCount: 4,
                              childAspectRatio: 0.56,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 2),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return GridItemCustom(
                            item: customExercises
                                .getCustomExercises()
                                .elementAt(index),
                            isSelected: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                if (value) {
                                  widget.selectedList.add(customExercises
                                      .getCustomExercises()
                                      .elementAt(index));
                                } else {
                                  widget.selectedList.remove(customExercises
                                      .getCustomExercises()
                                      .elementAt(index));
                                }
                              });
                              print("$index : $value");
                            },
                            key: Key(customExercises
                                .getCustomExercises()
                                .elementAt(index)
                                .uniqueKey
                                .toString()));
                      }),
            ),
```

My GridCustomItem is like:

```
class GridItemCustom extends StatefulWidget {
  final Key key;
  final ExerciseItem item;
  final ValueChanged<bool> isSelected;

  GridItemCustom(
      {required this.item, required this.isSelected, required this.key});

  String get2FirstLetters(String str) {
    String initial = "";
    List<String> words = str.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      initial += words[i].substring(0, 1);
    }
    return initial.toUpperCase();
  }

  @override
  _GridItemCustomState createState() => _GridItemCustomState();
}

class _GridItemCustomState extends State<GridItemCustom> {
  bool isSelected = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          isSelected = !isSelected;
          widget.isSelected(isSelected);
        });
      },
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomRight, children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(isSelected ? 0.9 : 0),
              child: Text(widget.get2FirstLetters(widget.item.title)),
            ),
            isSelected
                ? Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.check_circle,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        )),
                  )
                : Container(),
          ]),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Text(
            widget.item.title,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.orange,
                fontFamily: 'LibreBaskerville',
                fontSize: 10),
          ),
          //: Container()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time